# Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' angular 4

Tags: angular, checkbox

i am trying to get checkbox checked value from ts(type script) file. For this, I have a Boolean variable and the purpose is to show and hide div using this variable value but I am facing a problem. Please help me to solve this and also give me the right way to do this. Here is my code...

html code

```
**checkbox code**abcde" class="form-check-input" id="abcde" value="1"
(change)="checked('abcde')"> abcde
```

show and hide code

```
*ngIf='shown'
```

ts file

```
checked(value) {

    let get_id = document.getElementById('abcde');

    if (get_id.checked == true) {
        this.shown = true
    }
    else if (get_id.checked == false)
        this.shown = false;
}
```

When i run ng serve then I get "Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you use reactive form?

Comment: Try this `const get_id = document.getElementById('abcde') as HTMLInputElement;`

Comment: Take a look at how to insert [Code and Reformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) into your question. And edit your post.

Comment: i am using normal form not react form..thanks for your answer. Using const this is solved . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Typescript File (app.component.ts)         
    import { Component } from 'angular/core';
                @Component({
                  selector: 'app-root',
                  template: './app.component.html',
                  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
                })
                export class AppComponent {
                   public shown = false;
                } 

    //Html Code (app.component.html)
        <form #myForm='ngForm'>      
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" 
                     #checkBox="ngModel" 
                  [(ngModel)]="shown" name="checkBox">
        </form>
                <div *ngIf="shown"> 
                    <!---Your Code Here...--->
                </div>
```

Here, This is one of the way to do show and hide div element on basis of checkbox selection and deselection. Two way binding is done here with shown variable.

Answer (score 58):

Use this:

```
const ele = document.getElementById("idOfElement") as HTMLInputElement;
ele.checked = false;
```

Answer (score 6):

In your HTML

```
<input #abcde  type="checkbox" (change)="func()" />
```

In your component

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('abcde') abcde: ElementRef;
  func() {
    this.abcde.nativeElement.checked
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to your nodemodules folder

\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts

file name :`lib.dom.d.ts`

search for this 'Any HTML element. Some elements directly implement this interface' line no. 6374 (in my node module)

and in `interface HTMLElement` add  `checked: boolean;`

[see image where it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H4dU.png)

also you need to add in your global nodemodule also
press control and quick fix declare property  `checked: boolean;`

[see this image for global nodemodules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzAsL.png)