# typescript and html toggleswitch value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, toggleswitch

The short story is that I need to use a toggle switch to determine which of my methods are gonna be called. So I'm guessing that you can get a Boolean, referring to whether the switch is on or off? but how do I get that?

So I've implemented a toggleswitch in html

```
<label class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox" id="ToggleswitchId" >
 <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I've seen somebody do something like this, with javascript.

```
 var switchTrueFalse = document.getElementById('ToggleswitchId').checked
```

but all I get is "Property 'checked' does not exist on type HTMLElement"

Comment: .checked is not a function. Its a variable holding the checked state.

Comment: Are you using angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is not a method. It is one of the `<input>` attributes which is a boolean.

So, `document.getElementById('ToggleswitchId').checked` returns true when it is checked

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a property of checkbox input which returns true or false.

```js
function clickCheckbox() {
  if (document.getElementById('ToggleswitchId').checked) {
    console.log("check")
  } else {
    console.log("uncheck");
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox" id="ToggleswitchId" onClick="clickCheckbox()" >call method
 <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I've tried your code and .checked, doesn't work. "Property 'checked' does not exist on type HTMLElement".

Comment: Are you using Angular?

Comment: I use Angular CLI 7.1.4

Comment: As you are new to the Stack Overflow, so FYI you should tag the question with angular also, mention everything in the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002244/property-checked-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement-angular-4

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the advice regarding stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a JavaScript function on the check/uncheck of check box.

```js
function test() {
    var switchTrueFalse = document.getElementById('ToggleswitchId').checked;
    console.log(switchTrueFalse);
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ToggleswitchId" onclick="test()" >
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an input tag, try using `HTMLInputElement` instead of `HTMLElement`.

Try using this code instead, and see if it works:

```
document.getElementById("ToggleswitchId") as HTMLInputElement).checked
```